# Applying ARIMA in R

Tags: time-series, arima, autocorrelation

Small question as a follow up from this topic:
[Relationship between two time series: ARIMA](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27748/relationship-between-two-time-series-arima)

I am trying to reproduce the above through R. In the first steps, IrishStat applies AR(1) on doubly differenced x and single differenced y. However, after applying this filter in R, we obtain the following:

```
> ar1_12 <- arima(df1$x, order=c(1,2,0))
> ar2_12 <- arima(df1$y, order=c(1,1,0))
> ar1_12

Call:
arima(x = df1$x, order = c(1, 2, 0))

Coefficients:
ar1
-0.3761
s.e. 0.1306

sigma^2 estimated as 0.3199: log likelihood = -42.53, aic = 89.06
> ar2_12

Call:
arima(x = df1$y, order = c(1, 1, 0))

Coefficients:
ar1
-0.4815
s.e. 0.1213

sigma^2 estimated as 0.0328: log likelihood = 14.64, aic = -25.29
```

What can we conclude from this? Could you provide maybe some elaboration on the thought process regarding the cross-correlative structure of these two arima filters? Why is it that both autoregressive factors are -.383 in the example by IrishStat?

Comment: The -.383 value id based upon the doubly differenced X series. It is then applied to the suitably differenced Y series. The reason for using the one coefficient is to NOT distort the relationship but to identify the relationship between the original (OBSERVED) Y and the originally (OBSERVED) X .